# "Not Found" problem with QuestDB behind NGINX

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403, questdb

I am running a QuestDB 6.6.1-server. Now I want to increase the protection of this server and put the web gui behind an NGINX reverse proxy as described in [QuestDB blog post where setting up basic authentication is shown](https://questdb.io/blog/2022/08/05/setting-basic-auth-nginx).

When I try to open the QuestDB web gui, the login popup is displayed, I can enter name and password without issues. However, after having successfully passed the login popup, I only see a bare text "Not Found" in the browser (Note: but NOT the NGINX 403 Not Found screen, which I now in other cases). Neither nginx.log, nor questdb.log show entries.

[image]

It is POSSIBLE to reach the QuestDB web gui via <server.domain>:9000, no issues there.

The "location" settings are defined in a file `reverse_proxy.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name server.domain;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl_certificate <path>/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key <path>/nginx.key;
  
  root /var/www/server.domain/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name server.domain;

  location /location1 {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:port1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }

  location /location2 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:port2/location2;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
  }

  location = /questdb/ {

    auth_basic "Restricted QuestDB";
    auth_basic_user_file <path>/.htpasswd;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 120;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

`reverse_proxy.conf` is imported into `nginx.conf`. `nginx.conf` looks like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        # For suppression of server version number
        server_tokens off;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
   
        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##
        map_hash_max_size 262144;
        map_hash_bucket_size 262144;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using questdb on a directory. You are proxying to http://localhost:9000/questdb, and QuestDB is saying "Not found"

To avoid that, you would need to add a slash at the end of `proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;` as in `proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;`

Problem then is that relative URLs (/assets, /exec...) will not work and you will need to rewrite them on nginx.

It would be probably easier to just use a subdomain rather than a directory.

update: this is the nginx config I use. As explained, relative links are broken

```
location  /questdb/  {
proxy_pass  http://localhost:9000/;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            auth_basic "Restricted Content";
            auth_basic_user_file /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx.htpasswd;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Javier, tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work. Strange thing is, that the other location don't have a "/", but work as expected

Comment: Just updated my answer with the config I am using. With that I can get to questdb console main page, but CSS and JS are broken due to broken links. But it explains the "Not found" you were getting initially. I think a subdomain is easier for this

Comment: Hey, any update for using the subpath  /questdb/ or a subdomain is mandatory?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge nothing has been changed, but feel free to open an issue in the repository of the project so it can be tracked